# Hot deployment of modified axis archive for web services

Tags: apache-axis, hotdeploy

Apache axis2 (1.6.1) support hot deployment of web service archives when copied to axis war's web-inf/services folder. But this is limited to new services only. It does not hot deploy 'changed' services .. does anyone have a solution for handling 'changes' in the service archives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out a way to do this. Instead of 'over-writing' the service archive file, do a delete and copy of the archive file. Deleting the archive from the web-inf/services directory forces axis to automatically 'undeploy' the services and then adding the changed archive is treated as a 'new service archive' and is automatically deployed.